# MS Word wildcards VBA Macro search text inside a double curly in .doc files

Tags: vba, search, ms-word, wildcard

Please help!!!

I have a VBA macro for Microsoft Word that I am trying to fix.
The purpose of the macro is to match match anything that is inside a double curly braces {{anything}}, however braces must be open and close in the same line.
Once I have the match I need to be able to apply changes format, style, color etc. and apply some other changes selected text.

The .doc where I need to search has tables, draw text box and other objects, that's why I'd like to use the normal search from ms word.

Example:

```
{{1,000.00}}        match (1)
{{Interesting}}     match (1)
{{Within}}          match (1)
{{1’100.00’}}       match (1)
**{{01A10}}    {{01A10}}**   match (2) twice
 {{      1    }}    match (1)
{{10-}}          {{-10}}      match (2) twice
[[1252}}            No match (0)
{{8888888.99        No match (0), because close curly braces are in a new line
}}
{{}}                match (1)
{{1’000’000.05}}    match (1)
{{                  No match (0)
}}                  No match (0)
```

I have tried this "[{]{2}<*>[}]{2}" but it does not work it brings unwanted result.
any help will be very appreciated.

Hire is my code:

```
Sub GetTotalReport()
    Dim totalReport As Double
    Dim placeHolderRep As Variant
    Dim placeHolder As Variant

    ActiveDocument.Select

    totalReport = 0#
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[\{]{2}<*>[\}]{2}"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
          Do While .Execute
            With Selection
              .Font.Italic = True
              .Font.Bold = True
                If Not .Text = "" Then
                  placeHolderRep = Mid(.Text, 3, Len(.Text) - 4)
                 .Text = placeHolderRep
                  placeHolder = placeHolderRep
                  placeHolder = Replace(Replace(Replace(placeHolder, ",", ""), "'", ""), "’", "")
                  totalReport = totalReport + Val(placeHolder)
                End If
            End With
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
Selection.WholeStory

Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

p = "\{\{[^\{]*\}\}"
ary = Split(Selection, vbCr)

re.Global = True
re.Pattern = p

For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
    Set Matches = re.Execute(ary(i))
    Debug.Print ary(i) & ": " & Matches.Count
Next
```

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: Remou, thanks for your suggestion, but I see some problem using this code in my solution:
1. The document where I have to search can be up to 500 pages, I believe not array will support that amount of rows, and I believe performance will bad.
2. My documents are really complex and have tables and draw text box, so splitting the selection in with that method, does not get any text from tables or draw text box.
3. Once I've got the match I need to be able to change format and apply some changes to the text selected and your option does not give me that change, or i might be wrong on this one.